# HTML5: Div background size randomly wrong on mobile

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, dom

I'm developing a "fake" chat app with pre-defined messages. Ignore the actual content.

First of all it works perfectly fine on PC but seemingly at random the size of divs for shorter messages does not scale as wanted, so the message background (and the actual div i guess) is only half or 3/4 the size of what it should be and the message is spilling over to the side.

[image: Issue01]
[image: Issue02]

What's weird to me is that it works fine for most of the other messages (though some have line breaks i didn't add myself despite not being at max width) AND it seems to try to scale (see 2nd image) so it's not consistently the same wrong size.

I'm adding the messages using the .before JS/jQuery .
It's a div containing a paragraph thats being filled with a message from an array.
This is the code snippet

```js
// Delay between sending and displaying the new message. during this time the "..." is shown.
var msgAnimDelay = 500;

/* HTML wrappers for the message div */
const msgTheyHead = "<div class='message they'><p class='they'>";
const msgYouHead = "<div class='message you'><p class='you'>";
const msgEnd = "</p></div>"
/* messages in order, wrapped by divs above. y=yes, n=no, m=maybe, d=data, f=failed*/
const theirMessages = 
[
    "this is a medium length sentence this is a.", //t1
    "this is a medium length sentence this is a medium length sentence", //t2_n
    "mississippiii", //t2_y
    "this is a long sentencethis is a long sentencethis is a long sentencethis is a long sentencethis is a long sentencethis is a long sentencethis is a long sentencethis is a long sentencethis is a long sentence", //t3
    "this is a sentence with br <br> this is a long sentencethis is a long sentencethis is a long sentence heres another br <br> this is a medium sentencethis is a medium sentencethis is a medi", //t3_n
];

const yourMessages=
[
    "short phra", //q0
    "nayy", //q1_1
    "OK", //q1_2
    "this is a short sentence", //q2_1
    "this is a longer sentence a longer sentence a longer sentence a longer sentence", //q2_2
    "this is a very long sentence this is a very long sentence this is a very long sentence this is a very long sentence this is a very long sentence this is a very long sentence this is a very long sentence now a break <br> this is a very long sentencethis is a very long sentencethis is a very long sentencethis is a very long sentencethis is a very long sentencethis is a very long sentence", //q2_3
];

/* un-hides animation and calls show message after delay. */
function newThemMessage(msgID){
    $("#typing").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#chat-history").scrollTop($("#chat-history")[0].scrollHeight);
    setTimeout(showMessage, msgAnimDelay, true, msgID);
}

/* hides animation, plays sound, adds message from array, using the wrapper variables*/
function showMessage(bThem, msgID){
    if (bThem) {
        $("#typing").addClass("hidden");
        $("#typing").before(msgTheyHead + theirMessages[msgID] + msgEnd);
    } else {
        $("#typing").before(msgYouHead + yourMessages[msgID] + msgEnd);
    }
    //scroll down to newest message
    scrollToLatest();
}

// set height of chat history
function updateLayout(){
    var navHeight = $("#nav-bar").outerHeight(true);
    var choiceHeight = $("#chat-choices").outerHeight(true);
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var chatHeight = (windowHeight - (navHeight + choiceHeight)) + "px";
    $("#chat-history").css({"max-height": chatHeight, "height": chatHeight, "margin-top": navHeight});
}

function scrollToLatest(){
    $("#chat-history").scrollTop($("#chat-history")[0].scrollHeight);
}

/* Responses */
//q0
function clicked0(){
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * yourMessages.length);
    showMessage(false,randomIndex);
}
//q1
function clicked1(){
    var randomIndex =  Math.floor(Math.random() * theirMessages.length);
    newThemMessage(randomIndex);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    updateLayout();
    $(window).resize(updateLayout);
});
```

```css
/*
    INTERESTING STUFF at the bottom (line ~75)
*/

*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, h1, h2, h3, p {
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.3125rem;
    line-height: 1.6;
    background-color: #47434C;
}
h1, h2, h3 {
    font-weight: 900;
    line-height: 1;
}
.text-center{
    text-align: center;
}
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
div.hidden{
    display: none;
}
header, section{
    padding: 1rem 0;
}

.bg-light {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
.bg-dark {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
#nav-bar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
}

.btn{
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    background-color: #146aa0;
    color: WHITE;
    min-height: 3rem;
    padding: 0.6em 1.0em;
    margin-bottom: 0.7rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-inline: 0.5rem;
   
}

.flex-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}

/*
    INTERESTING STUFF STARTS HERE
    INTERESTING STUFF STARTS HERE
    INTERESTING STUFF STARTS HERE
*/

.container{
    margin-inline: auto;
    width:min(90%, 70.5rem);
}

.message{
    padding: 0.5rem;
    background-color: #F7F4EA;
    margin-bottom: 0.7rem;
    width: fit-content;
    max-width: min(70%, 40rem);
    
    block-size: fit-content;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

p.message{}
.you{
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #99D6FF;
}
.they{
    background-color: #F7F4EA;
}

p.you::before{
    content: "You";
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

p.they::before{
    content: "They";
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

#chat-history{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

#chat-choices{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 6rem;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>chatapp</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Navigation bar -->
    <header id="nav-bar" class="bg-dark text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>
                CHAT
            </h1>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Chatverlauf -->
    <section id="chat-history" class="bg-contrast">
        <div class="container">
            
            <div class="message they">
                <p class="they">
                    Hello HelloHelloHe lloH ello Hello<br><br>                    
                    This is some more text more text more text more text more text more text<br>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="message they">
                <p class="they">
                    click OK if you understood
                </p>
            </div>
            
            <div id="typing" class="message they hidden">
                <p id="typing-anim" class="they">...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Chat Responses -->
    <section id="chat-choices" class="bg-light">
        
        <div class="container flex-container">
            <!-- <p>this is the chat selection</p> -->
            <div id="q0" class="flex-container">
                <button class="btn" id="btn0_1" onclick="clicked0()">Add You-Message</button>
                <button class="btn" id="btn0_1" onclick="clicked1()">Add They-Message</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to add a [mre], specially a snippet with all HTML code ? Also, I suggest you to use `min-width: fit-content;`

Comment: @Elikill58 thanks! i updated it
also good idea with the min width, i'll definitely put it into the code

Comment: Perfect! For me it works: http://prntscr.com/1ww02ce

Comment: @Elikill58 did you test it on mobile? because here in the browser i also have 0 issues with my original solution^^

Comment: I just test it: http://prntscr.com/1ww1c6g

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand why this problem occur , I need to say that , pc and mobile have different resolution .In order to obtain the same thing , you need to update your css code with `@media (min-width: 568px) and (max-width: 1023px){}`
min-width mean the minim resolution ,when the modification occur ,and the max-width means the max resolution when the modifications occur.
In order to resolve this problem , you need tu use this syntax and in curly braces you need to modify the objects to match what you want.
Hope this was usepful!

Comment: thanks for the reply
though I'm not sure how this would help in this case since it's working for some messages but not others and it doesn't seem to stem from the resolution.
The container class is set to choose either a screen percentage as max width or a specific REM number to account for different screen sizes and the messages themselves are set to push from their respective sides (their messages from the left, your messages from the right)
I added a snippet if you want to test it :)

Answer (score 0):

Such as said in comment, you have to set a `min-width`.

You can set it manually in px, but in you case, the best way is to use `min-width: fit-content;` to set the minimal width to the current content (and keep normal width with normal rule)

Comment: thanks! I'll give it a go

Comment: sadly when i tested it it wouldn't work as wanted. without a regular width the div stretches to fill the entire width (ignoring max width). But with a min-width and the width set it defaults to the maximum width no matter how long the message is.

I'm guessing you tested the code i uploaded which is my original code without the min-width property^^
And just to clarify my code works 100% of the time in a pc browser (even with the dev mode phone layout) but there are issues when running it on an actual mobile browser on the device. Most messages are fine but some are as shown in the pics